# Convert string into LikedHashMap

Tags: scala

I have the following code where I am trying to convert a `String` into a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
val transactins: LinkedHashMap[String, Extraction] = entries.split("\n").map(
  t => {
    val x: List[String] = t.split("|").toList
    (x(0), Extraction(x(1), x(2), x(3)))
  }
).toMap
```

The string has the following format:

```
 "A|xxx|yyy|zzz\n
  B|xxx|yyy|zzz\n
  C|xxx|yyy|zzz\n"
```

My code doesn't compile because it doesn't return a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Error:(18, 7) polymorphic expression cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : [T, U]scala.collection.immutable.Map[T,U]
 required: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,Extraction]
    ).toMap
      ^
```

I have to idea how to do that though.
So how can I convert the expression to a `LinkedHashMap`?

I would like to use an immutable variable.

Comment: What is extraction here?

Comment: A case class with 3 `String` components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `LinkedHashMap`'s [`.apply`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap$@apply[A,B](elems:(A,B)*):CC[A,B]) method:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap
import scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap

scala> case class Extraction(s1: String, s2: String, s3: String);
defined class Extraction

scala> val entries = """A|xxx|yyy|zzz
     | B|xxx|yyy|zzz
     | C|xxx|yyy|zzz"""
entries: String =
A|xxx|yyy|zzz
B|xxx|yyy|zzz
C|xxx|yyy|zzz

scala> val transactins: LinkedHashMap[String, Extraction] = LinkedHashMap(entries.split("\n").map(
         t => {
           val x: List[String] = t.split("|").toList
           (x(0), Extraction(x(1), x(2), x(3)))
         }):_*
       )
transactins: scala.collection.mutable.LinkedHashMap[String,Extraction] = Map(A -> Extraction(|,x,x), B -> Extraction(|,x,x), C -> Extraction(|,x,x))
```

Note that the `.apply` method takes a varying number of argument (denoted by the `*`
in `(elems: (A, B)*)`), so you need to use `:_*` to convert the `Array[(String, Extraction)]` to `(String, Extraction)*`.